# Why Debian 9.1 Desktop Icons burn through in Gnome 3.22 on X11?

Tags: debian, x11, gnome3

I have noticed that the Debian Desktop icons burn through i.e. show up on the screen when they should not in some dynamic cases

- Assistive technology On Screen Keyboard On
- Debian `reportbug` active while moving mouse on top of terminal links

I will add here a screenshot if I manage to capture one while the effect is occurring.

Problem: artefacts occurring in graphical interface when interaction with the mouse
Differential condition: hardware problem, motherboard etc.

OS: Debian 9.1
Window manager: Gnome 3.22 on X11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep getting those artifacts long time. 
Their amount decreased to none after changing Gnome start with *Wayland* instead of X11. 
So I think conflicts of X11 with the processes caused those artifacts, indicating a software problem, not a hardware problem.